# osx launchd plist with dynamic login username

Tags: launchd

Is possible to dynamic username(regard with logged in user) in .plist file for launchd.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.software.script</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/$username/script.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I want username is vary with logged in user
like this.

```
<string>/Users/user1/script.sh</string>
```

or

```
<string>/Users/user2/script.sh</string>
```

or

```
<string>/Users/usern/script.sh</string>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answered this... My solution would be to have a single script in a single location such as /usr/local/bin that just calls the appropriate user's script. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Users/`id -un`/script.sh
```

Or I am not sure if $HOME would be set but you might be able to use that.